# How to enable and disable a progress indicator when using JMS in javafx8

Tags: jms, javafx-8, fxml, progress-indicator

on action i send a message to a jms topic to process data and i have a call back method which gets called when the data is ready and loads a TableView.

```
public void onEnter(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        progressIndicator.setVisible(true);
                        scrollPane.setDisable(true);
                    });


                    //  Construct the message and publish it to a topic

                };
            }.start();

        } 
    }



public void callBackMethod(List<Object>  list )  {

        progressIndicator.setVisible(false);
        scrollPane.setDisable(false);
    //load data in the table
}
```

This does what i want, but what if something goes wrong at the messaging system end , the call back never gets called and the UI component will be disabled forever .

Any suggestions to improve this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the messaging system is going to throw some kind of exception if it fails to send the message, so you'll need a way to catch that and recover properly.  If you use the JavaFX "Task" class, then you'll get events when that happens.  You'll still have to deal with a failure at the receiving end, or implement some kind of a time-out, if that's appropriate.

Also, you're starting up a thread and then immediately tossing a job onto the FXAT with RunLater.  The onEnter event handler, by definition, is already running on the FXAT, so you can just do your GUI stuff before you start up the thread (or Task, as I suggest).  Here's a sample that shows how to launch the Task, and clean up if it fails with an exception:

```
public class SampleTask extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(0);
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    Button button = new Button("Start");
    root.setTop(progressIndicator);
    root.setCenter(scrollPane);
    progressIndicator.setVisible(false);
    root.setBottom(button);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();

    button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        progressIndicator.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setDisable(true);
        Task<Void> testTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // Send the message
                return null;
            }
        };
        testTask.setOnFailed(event -> {
            progressIndicator.setVisible(false);
            scrollPane.setDisable(false);
        });
        new Thread(testTask).start();
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if i understand it correctly , setOnFailed is called when there is a failure while sending/processing the message to the messaging system and messaging system is able to the throw back the error to the caller. If this phase goes fine with out any issues, then at the receiving end i should have some kind of time-out behaviour .

Comment: Mostly right.  For all practical purposes, the setOnFailed is called when the call() method of the Task throws an exception.  So, if you have a failure in messaging that you can actually receive and process in your call() method code, then setOnSuccess will be invoked.  In that case, maybe instead of have the call() (and the Task) return Void, it can return something more meaningful that you can deal with in the setOnSuccess method.  Remember that onFail and onSuccess code are executed on the FXAT.

Comment: Got it.. Thank you